# Using MSTest with CruiseControl.NET

Tags: msbuild, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

We have been using CruiseControl for quite a while with NUnit and NAnt.  For a recent project we decided to use the testing framework that comes with Visual Studio, which so far has been adequate.

I'm attempting to get the solution running in CruiseControl. I've finally got the build itself to work; however, I have been unable to get any tests to show up in the CruiseControl interface despite adding custom build tasks and components designed to do just that.  Does anyone have a definitive link out there to instructions on getting this set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if that helps (i found the ccnet Documentation somewhat unhelpful at times):

[Using CruiseControl.NET with MSTest](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+MSTest)

Answer (score 1):

The CC.Net interface is generated via an XSL transform on your XML files put together as specified in the ccnet.config file for your projects.  The XSL is already written for things like FxCop - check your server's CC xsl directory for examples - shouldn't be too hard to write your own to add in the info - just remember to add the XML output from your tests into the main log.